# Issue on Stop Sliding a List to Left and Right on First and Last Child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple Carousel slider at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CXRP5/1/). As you can see the slider works fine! but I do not know how to stop it at both end(left and right) side. I mean how can I control to disable the `left` btn when the first child of `ul` is the first displaying( visible) item at left and disable the `Right` btn while the last child of `<ul>` is rendering in the `.well` box?

Here is the simple code which I have so far:

```
$(".leftslide").on("click",function(){
   $(".list-inline").animate({left:'-=187px'}, 300);   
});
$(".rightslide").on("click",function(){
   $(".list-inline").animate({left:'+=187px'}, 300);   
});

var maginLeft =  $("ul>:first-child").css("marginLeft");
var maginRight = $("ul>:last-child").css("marginRight");

alert(maginLeft + maginRight );
```

I tried to control this by using  `var maginLeft =  $("ul>:first-child").css("marginLeft");` but it didnt do the job!

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure why you want margin information... you can get the current position of the carousel with `$(".list-inline").css("left")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do something like this:

```
$(".leftslide").on("click",function(){
    rightbtn.removeAttr("disabled");
    current++;
    if(current+images_shown >= images.length) {
         leftbtn.attr("disabled","disabled")
    }
    console.log(imageWidth+offset);  
    var qty=Math.ceil(imageWidth+offset);
    if(current+images_shown==images.length) qty+=offset;
    list.animate({left:'-='+qty+'px'}, 300);

});
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/CXRP5/6/

You still need to do something about clicking several times before animation ends though, but this should give you an idea of how to approach the problem

Comment: Thanks juvian this is perfect but can you please let me know how to stop slider when the first item is the FIRST at .well? I mean your solution is working perfectly but it is sliding the item to left or right until the end! what I have in my mine is not showing empty area in the .well

Comment: @MonaCoder You mean you always want to have 4 pictures showing instead of blank space?

Comment: well this is suppose to be a responsive layout so I cant say I always have 4 in the box but you are right let's get rid if the blank space and slide until there is item and no more. Thanks

Comment: @MonaCoder check new fiddle